# How to jump exactly 10 records ahead/back in a table (Laravel)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The problem I have is that my id(s) are not sequential. Meaning after id 95 might come 101 and then 103 and then 123 etc. 
Hence, if I were to just add 10 to the id I would get 105. Problem 1 -> id with 105 doesn't exist. Problem 2 -> I only jumped 3 ids.

Possible solution:

```
$currentUser = User::find(95);
$nextUserID = User::where('id', '>', $currentUser->id)->min('id');
```

and loop 10x using this to find next items times 10?

Is there a better way to this?

Comment: Have you tried chunking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to skip next 10 users from the current one, use [`skip()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) method:

```
User::where('id', '>=', 95)->skip(10)->first();
```

Comment: Nice and clean :)

Comment: @Alexey Menzenin Is there also a way to go back 10 records. Skip is going forward as I imagine! Thanx.

Comment: @stepbystep sure, just do it like this `User::where('id', '<=', 95)->skip(10)->first();`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I have tested `User::where('id', '<=', 95)->skip(10)->first();`. I think this does not work. It always start counting from the very first record and skips from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skip()` and then `take()` followed by `get()` or `first()` to get records like this:

```
$nextUserID = User::where('id', '>', $currentUser->id)->skip(10)->first();
```

With this you can get first row after 10 records.

You can use take() to get n records after skiping 10 records like this:

```
$next_nrows = User::where('id', '>',$currentUser->id)->skip(10)->take(n)->get();
```

See official docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the reverse of skipping 10 (say go back 10 records) then use the following:

```
User::where('id', '<=', 95)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->skip(10)->first();
```